# Regular expression for password in php

Tags: php

I want regular expression for password in php that must match following conditions  :

- 1) password must contain at least one letter and one digit.
- 2) password can be start from letter or number.

eg. adfjs345, 454dkfj, kfj45kj45, 870jdfk56fdjk are valid input.

Answer (score 1):

1- password must contain at least one letter and one digit

> /^(?:[0-9]+[a-z]|[a-z]+[0-9])[a-z0-9]*$/i

2- password start with letter or number

> ^[a-zA-z0-9]+

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. Use two regular expressions.

```
if( preg_match("[a-zA-Z]", $password) && preg_match("[0-9]", $password) ) {
    all_ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z\d]

(?=.*\d) - string contains digit
(?=.*[A-Za-z]) - string contains letter
^[A-Za-z\d] - string starts with letter or number
```

**[demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/gZ5qT3/3)**